# Lock a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, locking

I want to Lock a table in oracle and then check if it is blocked,
But i cant Lock a Table.
I tried doing this to lock:

```
LOCK TABLE CLIENTS IN EXCLUSIVE MODE
```

this es the query to Lock , but i can still upadate in that table

then check if its Blocked:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT l 
INNER JOIN DBA_OBJECTS d ON l.object_id = d.object_id 
WHERE d.object_type = 'TABLE' AND d.object_name = 'CLIENTS'
```

How can I Lock a table and then check if its blocked with php.

Comment: I'm not sure you got it wrong. LOCK command you posted will lock the table and nobody **except you** will be able to do anything with it (apart from selecting rows).

Comment: Which begs the question of _why_ you want to lock the table.  Oracle's transaction and locking mechanism are entirely different from other rdbms products you may be familiar with. It is _extremely_ rare to need to explicitly lock a table in oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `for update` :

`select * from clients for update`

to lock the table's whole records in exclusive mode ( `ROW_X (SX): Row Exclusive Table Lock` --> *"locked mode 3"* ), but it's not recommended for production systems. At least lock for only restricted set of records filtering by `where` clause.

Your statement (`LOCK TABLE CLIENTS IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`) also locks whole table and called `Exclusive (X): Exclusive Table Lock` --> *"locked mode 6"* as the command with `for update` above, i.e. logic works for both `SX` and `X` locks wherenever the select statement is without a `where` clause. But in the first method, there's a chance to restrict the number of the records which are impacted by the locking operation.

> *`commit` or `rollback` should be issued to release the lock for both cases( 
>   `SX` or `X` type locks ).*

Comment: Im just testing not in production , i want to Lock a table for update,insert,delete

Comment: @Leoh OK, try this then.

Comment: But How is the query to Lock the table: LOCK TABLE CLIENTS IN EXCLUSIVE MODE doesnt Lock the table

Comment: @Leoh yes you can, I just added a detailed explanation.

Comment: Im using this query to check if is Locked: SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT l INNER JOIN DBA_OBJECTS d ON l.object_id = d.object_id WHERE d.object_type = 'TABLE' AND d.object_name = 'CLIENTS';

Comment: @Leoh this query returns the same result for both locking style applied.

Comment: How could I return a specific record not the entire table ?

Comment: @Leoh by filtering with `where` such as `select * from clients for update where id = :i_id`. It's a critical and might be harmful job not using a `where` filter and then locking whole table.